# Evaluating expression statements from a text file in C++

Tags: c++

I am altering a (well, my first) C++ program that evaluates expressions. For example, by inputting this:

```
(x + (y * 3)), x = 2, y = 6;
```

It should output the following:

```
Value = 20
```

**The program works when the user types the expression into the console, but I want it to read and evaluate expressions from a text file (each on a separate line).** I have successfully read the file in, and can even print its contents in the console, but I'm having trouble parsing and evaluating each line. There are many more header and source files that accompany this project, but I think all of the relevant information is in the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#include "expression.h"
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "symboltable.h"
#include "parse.h"

SymbolTable symbolTable;

void parseAssignments();

int main()
{
    Expression* expression;
    char paren, comma;
    string program;

    ifstream myfile("expressions.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, program))
        {
            cout << program << '\n'; //confirms that file was read properly

            //code to parse expressions and print results
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    //original code that parses expression the user inputs
    /*cout << "Enter expression: ";
    cin >> paren;
    expression = SubExpression::parse();
    cin >> comma;
    parseAssignments();
    cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << end1;*/

    cin.get(); //added this so the window doesn't close automatically
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried numerous approaches over the last couple days, and I think it comes down to my C++ ignorance of what exactly is happening on these two lines. My theory is that it parses everything to the right of the parenthesis in the first line, and everything to the right of the comma in the second line (ignoring the fact that the scopes would overlap).

```
    cin >> paren;
    cin >> comma;
```

Therefore, among other approaches, I tried including the following in the while loop. I am using MS Visual Studio, and when I click "> Local Windows Debugger" it will open up a console window with the first expression printed and a blinking line like it's waiting for me to input something. I close out of the window, and instead of a "> Continue" in place of "> Local Windows Debugger" it will just end the program. It is entirely possible that I'm just using Visual Studio incorrectly.

```
myfile >> paren;
expression = SubExpression::parse();
myfile >> comma;
parseAssignments();
cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate();
```

And this:

```
std::istringstream iss(program);
iss >> paren;
expression = SubExpression::parse();
iss >> comma;
parseAssignments();
cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate();
```

And of course this:

```
getline(myfile, program) >> paren;
expression = SubExpression::parse();
getline(myfile, program) >> comma;
parseAssignments();
cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate();
```

Am I taking the completely wrong approach here, or worse should I be focusing on changing other functions as well? Thank you!!

**EDIT:** It appears that `cin >>` was being called in `parse()` and a few other .cpp files, which prevented my three attempts above from having much of an effect. Right now I'm looking into including the line as an argument in functions like below. I will report any errors if it doesn't work.

```
string parseName()
{
    char alnum;
    string name = "";

    cin >> ws;
    while (isalnum(cin.peek()))
    {
        cin >> alnum;
        name += alnum;
    }
    return name;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: IT WORKS!!! Since `cin >>` was being used throughout the program, I had to create a new variable `std::stringstream in(program);` and then use that as arguments in functions as seen below:

```
void parseAssignments(stringstream& in);

int main()
{
    Expression* expression;
    char paren, comma;
    string program;

    ifstream myfile("expressions.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, program))
        {
            cout << program << '\n'; //confirms that file was read properly

            std::stringstream in(program);
            in >> paren;
            expression = SubExpression::parse(in);
            in >> comma;
            parseAssignments(in);
            cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << '\n\;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    cin.get(); //added this so the window doesn't close automatically
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help guys! I think I'm going to go back to something a bit simpler with C++ and build up from there...

Comment: Can you be more specific than "with no success"?

Comment: Why did the `stringstream` version not work?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: What do you think `cin >> comma` and `cin >> paren` do, and how much of the input do the parse functions read?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, I updated my post to reflect my responses. @Jonas I'm not sure why stringstream didn't work, I was hoping you guys could tell me I was being dumb. haha

Comment: This is ambitious for a first program!

Comment: `myfile` is a stream **exactlly like** `cin`. Whatever works for `cin` should also work for `myfile`.

Comment: @aschepler I should say, first after Hello World. I'm just editing something that already works here so I thought it would be simpler.

Comment: @n.m. Is it possible I'm just using Visual Studio incorrectly (see post)?

Comment: Try learn to walk before you can run. Something between this and "hello world "

Comment: Agree with  ^ed. Evaluating `( 2 + ( 3 * 6 ) )` (note: spaces, no variables) is already a challenge. Perhaps you should even consider `2 3 6 * +` (Reverse Polish Notation). Infix may be familiar, but parentheses are hard.

Comment: Google for: bison flex expression.

Comment: I agree that it's a little ambitious. But the code is already written and the parsing itself works as it is, I'm just trying to get it to read expressions from the text file and not from the console.

Comment: parseAssignments() has no input, so ... something inside there has a side effect which is different.  Maybe it uses cin.  You should instead pass it the common base class for cin and ifstream.  What is that, istream?  And call it with parseAssignments(cin) or parseAssignments(myfile)

Comment: **Throw it all away** and look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm, or recursive descent expression parsing. You will never get there from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with this

```
cin >> paren;
expression = SubExpression::parse();
cin >> comma;
```

This code reads a single character from cin (the terminal), then calls parse, then reads another single character.  It never reads your expression.  It also never does anything with the two single characters, it just throws them away.

This says to me that the code that reads the expression from the terminal is in `SubExpression::parse()` -- that code (which you don't show) apparently reads directly from cin.

This indicates immediately why all your attempts have failed -- you have your expression in a file or a string, but your parse routine is still stubbornly reading from cin.  You need to change that routine to read from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense about reading the expression from `SubExpression::parse()`, and sure enough I found cin in not only parse.cpp but 2 other .cpp files as well! I am in the process of correcting these with `myfile >>` instead, but should I be instantiating the `ifstream myfile("expressions.txt");` along with wrapping in the same  if and while loops each time? I think the answer is no, but I'm not sure what the alternative is.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks again, you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Syk3: better would be to make `parse` take an `istream &` arg and read from that.